# Get from a transformation matrix to the resultant span of the solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Guess that's a very basic question, but anyway:

I have the following transformation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{3}\\ 0 & -6 & -3 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$
And I know that the span of the solution set is $Sp\{(2, -1, 0, 6), (0, -1, 2, 0)\}$. But how do I get it?

I always thought that solving such matrix requires using parameters, so the solution would always be a general one (i.e., parameterized). But I guess that's not the case.

(If there's some missing part here, please let me know)

Comment: Can you give a definition of a span of a matrix?  I've not heard this term used before.  I know what the span of a set of vectors is.  And I know what the image (or range) of a matrix is.  But I'm not sure what the span of a matrix is.

Comment: Why, of course not; I'll edit

Comment: @NicNic8, I think it's better now

Comment: What is a solution set of a matrix?  I think part of your issue may be that you're not using correct terminology.  If we have an equation Ax=b, then we might ask "What are the values of x that satisfy this equation?"  Another way to ask this is "What are the solutions to this equation?"  But I've never heard of a solution set for a matrix.  The set that you're calling the solution set looks to be the Null space of the matrix.  Is that what you're going after?  That's the special set of solutions to Ax=0, where A is the matrix of interest.

Comment: What I mean is "the solution set of (the linear equations system represented by) the matrix". Is that a good terminology?

Comment: The span of a pair of vectors is the set of all of their linear combinations, in this case $\lambda(2,-1,0,6)+\mu(0,-1,2,0)$, et voilà, there’s your parameterization. The two ways of describing the set are equivalent.

Comment: @HeyJude A matrix does not represent a linear system of equations.

Comment: @NicNic8, why not? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_equation) is no proof, but just to have some reference: "In row reduction (also known as Gaussian elimination), the linear system is represented as an augmented matrix"

Comment: @HeyJude Oh!  You're right; a matrix CAN represent a linear system of equations.  Generally, a matrix does not represent a linear system of equations.  And if we had a matrix, the linear system of equations would be represented by Ax = b.  The augmented matrix would be [ A | b ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the null space of a matrix, one wants to solve the equation $Ax=0$, where $A$ is the matrix of interest.  Let's do this for your case.

We want to find all the $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that
$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{3}\\ 0 & -6 & -3 & -1\end{bmatrix}}_{A} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Therefore we know
\begin{aligned}
  x_1 - (1/3) x_4 &= 0 \\
  -6 x_2 - 3 x_3 - x_4 &= 0
\end{aligned}
We have two equations, but we have four variables.  Therefore, if the equations are not redundant, we'll end up with a two dimensional vector space as the null set.  Let's find this vector space.

Let $x_4=s$  Then we know that $x_1=(1/3)s$.  Let $x_3=t$  Then we know that 
$$-6x_2 -3t -s=0.$$
Equivalently, this shows us that $x_2 = t/2 - s/6$.  This shows us that any vector in the null space of A is of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1/3 s \\ t/2 - s/6 \\ t \\ s
\end{bmatrix} = 
s\begin{bmatrix}1/3 \\ -1/6 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1/2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},$$
where $s$ and $t$ are real numbers.  Another way to state that is
$$\text{null}(A) = \text{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1/3 \\ -1/6 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1/2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right)= \text{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 6\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much, learned some new things from this discussion.

Comment: @HeyJude My pleasure!